# Input/output error for specific files on external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, android

I have a UnionSine external hard drive connected via USB. I formatted it as exFAT, it mounted as expected and I put some files on it. I hooked it up to an NVidia Shield and read some of the files. Now when I connect it back to Ubuntu, I see that two files have been added: NVIDIA_SHIELD and LOST.DIR, which give an input/output error when I attempt to view the drive's root directory:

```
$ ls -l /media/jared/7902-883D/
ls: cannot access '/media/jared/7902-883D/LOST.DIR': Input/output error
ls: cannot access '/media/jared/7902-883D/NVIDIA_SHIELD': Input/output error
total 768
drwxr-xr-x 5 jared jared 131072 Jul  5 00:23 Android
d????????? ? ?     ?          ?            ? LOST.DIR
drwxr-xr-x 2 jared jared 655360 Jul  4 23:28 NES
d????????? ? ?     ?          ?            ? NVIDIA_SHIELD
```

I have tried exfatfsck, smartctl and badblocks and none have found any errors. Is there some way I can fix or remove these files so that I can use file manager on this drive?

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.13.0-21-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Hitachi HCC545012B9A300
Serial Number:    100118PB5B00QCER093G
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 5a2e63046
Firmware Version: PBJVCC0D
User Capacity:    120,034,123,776 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Tue Jul  5 22:13:06 2022 PDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  645) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  47) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   201   201   033    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       6935
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   088   088   000    Old_age   Always       -       5691
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       71
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       61
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7158
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   177   177   000    Old_age   Always       -       31 (Min/Max 18/38)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      5683         -
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               80%      5682         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5682         -
# 4  Short captive       Completed without error       00%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think there's anything wrong with your drive. It seems to be a feature of the NVIDIA SHIELD to create these 2 directories ('NVIDIA_SHIELD' and 'LOST.DIR').

I recently took a thumb drive formatted in exFAT to my brother, who has a SHIELD. And when I got home I noticed it had those 2 directories on it. I can't access them, cd into them, move them or delete them. They can't be accessed.

I'm not yet sure if they behave like this strictly on exFAT, or if it's like this regardless of the file system. When I try to open the thumb drive in Nautilus, I can't. Because it tries to read all the filetypes in that directory, and when it fails to read those 2 directories it throws an error and shows the directory as empty.

However, changing into the drive directory in Bash allows me to access the drive just fine, read from it and write to it, just not those 2 specific file names. At first, I thought maybe the partition had gotten corrupted, so I repaired it with Gparted and it showed no errors. I also thought that maybe because the exFAT driver in Linux is only a couple of years old, maybe this is some sort of bug.

I will find out soon, as my brother bought a new external hard drive for his SHIELD and he wants to bring it to my place so I can format it in exFAT and move everything over from his old external drive which is formatted in NTFS. I will test if those 2 directories can be accessed on the NTFS drive, and then I will know if it's an issue specific to exFAT or the SHIELD in general.

Anyway, your drive is most likely fine and you can still use it. A trick is to move everything but those 2 file names to a sub-directory and using that. If you do that, you can use that sub-directory just fine even in Nautilus. It just has problems when the 2 special file names are in the same directory as what you're trying to open. But, you still won't be able to open the drive directly as it's mounted in Nautilus. You will have to cd into the sub-directory you've created in Bash and do 'nautilus .' to open it graphically.

I will come back to this thread with a follow-up after I've helped my brother out with his external drives. Which will most likely be 1 or 2 weeks from now.

Until then, I created a small shell script in preparation for backing up his old drive. It takes a path as argument (the path to your drive, which is most likely something like '/run/media/yourusername/whatevernameyourdrivehas'), and it moves every file and directory in there to a sub-directory so you can have easier access. I probably need to do this even though that drive uses NTFS, if my theory is correct. Or else 'cp -rp' will throw errors when I try to copy the drive directory to the new drive, since those 2 file names can't be accessed.

Here's a link to the script, in case you're interested:
https://github.com/linux4ever07/scripts/blob/main/nv_shield_dn.sh

*** EDIT ***

Well, it turns out I could read the 'NVIDIA_SHIELD' and 'LOST.DIR' directories on my brother's old NTFS drive. It might be that NTFS and exFAT behave differently in this regard, or it might be because my brother's drive used a GPT partition table, whereas my thumb drive (which had trouble reading the directories) used a classic MSDOS partition table. It's either the difference in partition table or file system that caused the issue. The only other explanation is the thumb drive might've gotten slightly corrupted cause my brother didn't eject it properly before unplugging it from his SHIELD.

I hope this helps.